# Trying to understand DropDownListFor, default selection is showing up twice?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, strongly-typed-view

The following code "works", but the final results are not what I expected. I get a `dropdownlist` with all countries as expected; the default being United States at the very top of the list. But, United States still remains as selectable  if you scroll down the list, I now have two "United States" entries...

Also worth noting that in my validation, the default "United States" selection is consider invalid, that is, it shows me validation message to "please select a country". If I then select the "United States" entry located further down the list, the validation message disappears.

Why is this happening? Am I understanding this incorrectly?

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{

    public class CountriesDropdown
    {
        public string defaultSelection { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropdownViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public CountriesDropdown countriesDropdownViewModel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Country of Residence: ")]
    public string CountryResidence { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.CountryResidence, Model.countriesDropdownViewModel.dropdownViewModel, Model.countriesDropdownViewModel.defaultSelection, new { style = "max-width: 215px;", id = "cbCountry", @class = "validate[required]" })
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
private ProfileViewModel PopulateAllDropdown(ProfileViewModel model)
{
   model.countriesDropdownViewModel = new ProfileViewModel.CountriesDropdown();
   model.countriesDropdownViewModel.dropdownViewModel = _DBCall.GetCountriesDropdownListPopulated();
   model.countriesDropdownViewModel.defaultSelection  = "United States";

   return model;
}
```

Comment: of course it will show two one time it is popuplated from database and second one you are shwing in default text which in most cases Select One or Select Country

Comment: cab you show ``GetCountriesDropdownListPopulated()`` definition you need to set default selected one from their

Comment: Thank you Ehsah Sajjad, after reading your comment I was able to fix it. I moved the default selection inside the `GetCountriesDropdownListPopulated()` code and works fine. Why not post it as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it will shown two times inside the drop-down list because one time it is populated from database using `GetCountriesDropdownListPopulated()` and second one that is shown is because you are adding it as default text which in most cases we put **Select One** or **Select Country**, so you need to select default selection inside the `GetCountriesDropdownListPopulated()` method.

Answer (score 0):

please set the **AppendDataBoundItems="false"** in DropDownList

For Example:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="false">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```